# How to install FB Customer Chat Plugin to my WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-customer-chat

How to install Customer Chat Plugin? I am not a developer so please explain easily.

For your reference, I am using a WordPress and URL is `moonbow.in`.

1) I added my website domain https://moonbow.in to on whitelist at first.

2) I copied code below and paste it to footer.php on my website.

```
> <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript --> <div id="fb-root"></div>
> <script>(function(d, s, id) {   var js, fjs =
> d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;   js
> = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;   js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
> fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script',
> 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
> 
> <!-- Your customer chat code --> <div class="fb-customerchat"  
> attribution="setup_tool"   page_id="548879948844197"  
> theme_color="#0084ff"> </div>
```

I still can not find Customer Chat Plugin on my website.

And I tried to do something on developers.facebook.com even I failed to get a token.

[image]

Comment: I can see the chat window on the right bottom corner of your site so I guess you already figured it out.

Comment: If you actually put those `>` symbols in your JS code, it won't work. If they are a formatting error in your question, please remove them.